# Unable to buy Azure Domain for Service Plan Shared

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I try to buy a domain for my Web App, I get the message that I have to get an Azure subscription. I have a paid Azure subscription, but it was a DreamSpark Account before.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This means that this is not available on your current subscription. buy a domain from any vendor and then configure it on your web app to use this custom domain. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I did this at the end... Anyway, I had all the prerequisites to buy domains, so this means another thing that we don't know. Azure has bugs too. we are Microsoft  Partner and had a lot of problems with Azure...